# Create Row Labels based on an existing label in R

Tags: r

I have a df with a label "S" for anywhere my numeric column is <35.
I'd like to use each S position and label "S-1", "S-2", "S-3" for the 3 previous rows to S, then "S+1", "S+2" for the next 2 rows of S.

like this..

```
N    S
45   
56   
67   S-3
47   S-2
52   S-1
28   S
89   S+1
66   S+2
55 
76
```

I was using this to start me off, just as an example.

```
n <- sample(50:100, 10, replace=T)

data <- data.frame(N=n)
data <- rbind(data, 30)
data <- rbind(data,data,data,data,data,data)
data$S <- ifelse(data$N<35, "S", "")
```

Any ideas..?

Comment: What happens if you have two `<35` entries in a row?

Comment: May I recommend that you not do it this way? :)  What are you going to use the `S` column for later?  Blank elements in a column in your data frame should generally be avoided. If you want a structure that identifies a location or a distance to a location in a column, there are other ways to do this.

Comment: I won't ever have 2 35's in a row, there will always be at least 10 rows between each that is <35

Comment: Dan Hall  - thats exactly what I'd like to know, I provided code to illustrate the example

Comment: You said you'd like a df "like this". Your "this" has a column with a lot of blank values and, I suppose, a factor that tracks a single position and a distance from that position.  I'm suggesting you use a different structure to achieve whatever you're trying to do with that column, but I don't know what that is. What are you going to use that column for? What behavior are you trying to get out of your data?

Comment: I'm hoping to summarise what N values occur at the various S positions, so at the end I'd have perhaps another df that would have S values as columns and each row would house the various N values

Comment: @LodewicVanTwillert's use of lag and lead are appropriate. I'd just use the expressions when you want to use them.. when you're summarizing the N values. `data$N[which(lag(N <35, 2))]` for example.

Comment: Or of course, `filter(data, lag(N < 35, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an option using `base R`, where we get the index of rows where 'N' is less than 35 ('i1'), create the 'S' column with blank (`""`) elements, loop through 'i1', get the sequence of 3 elements before, 2 elements after, `paste` with 'S', get the `intersect` of sequence with the index ('ind') and assign the strings ('val') to the 'S' column

```
i1 <- which(data$N < 35)
data$S <- ""
out <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(i1, function(i) data.frame(ind =(i-3): (i+2), 
   val = c(paste0("S-", 3:1), "S", paste0("S+", 1:2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
i2 <- out$ind %in% seq_len(nrow(data))

data$S[out$ind[i2]] <- out$val[i2]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
n <- sample(50:100, 10, replace=T)

data <- data.frame(N=n)
data <- rbind(data, 30)
data <- rbind(data,data,data,data,data,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without dealing with possible overlap, here is a bunch of `ifelse()` statements to get the job done. Maybe you can think of a more appropriate way to generalize it.

You can use `lag()` and `lead()` with the `dplyr` package.

```
data %>% mutate(S = ifelse(S == "S", S,
                           ifelse(lag(S == "S"), "S+1",
                                  ifelse(lag(S == "S", 2), "S+2",
                                         ifelse(lead(S == "S"), "S-1",
                                                ifelse(lead(S == "S", 2), "S-2", ""))))),
                S = ifelse(is.na(S), "", S))
```

(You would get NA values in the first two rows if the first value is not <35, so replace these with "".)

```
     N   S
1   52    
2   86    
3   86    
4   57    
5   54    
6   57    
7   51    
8   98    
9  100 S-2
10  73 S-1
11  30   S
12  52 S+1
13  86 S+2
14  86
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-ish answer since I break it down into pieces I would normally implement using a pipeline and lambda expressions, but it should be easy enough to follow.

I will work on row indices and compute two vectors, one containing the index closest to `i` on the left that has label `"S"`, and one containing the index closest to `i` on the right.

```
indices <- 1:length(data$S)
closest_left  <- rep(NA, length = length(indices))
closest_right <- rep(NA, length = length(indices))
```

I compute these using `purrr`'s reduce functions but you could easily do it in a loop as well.

```
this_or_left <- function(left_val, i) { 
    res <- if (data$S[[i]] == "S") i else left_val
    closest_left[[i]] <<- if (data$S[[i]] == "S") i else left_val
}
this_or_right <- function(right_val, i) { 
    res <- if (data$S[[i]] == "S") i else right_val
    closest_right[[i]] <<- if (data$S[[i]] == "S") i else right_val
}

purrr::reduce(indices, this_or_left, .init = this_or_left(NA, 1))
purrr::reduce_right(indices, this_or_right, .init = this_or_right(NA, length(indices)))
```

Whether you could do it with vectorised expressions I don't know. Possibly. I didn't try.

Now, I simply have to compute the distance to the closest S and make labels from that, using empty labels if the distance is greater than 3 and label `"S"` if the distance is zero.

```
get_dist <- Vectorize(function(i) {
    down <- i - closest_left[i] 
    up <- closest_right[i] - i
    if (is.na(down) || down > up) up
    else if (is.na(up) || down <= up) -down
    else NA
})
make_label <- Vectorize(function(dist) {
    if (abs(dist) > 3) ""
    else if (dist == 0) "S"
    else if (dist < 0) paste0("S", dist)
    else if (dist > 0) paste0("S+", dist)
})

make_label(get_dist(indices))
```

Here, I used `Vectorize`d expressions to change it up a little.